# Inserting data in MySQL using flex TextInput and Button

Tags: database, flex4, flash-builder

I am trying to add data to mysql database. There is a single textInput for entering name and a Button.(addBtn) on click of which the textInput.text should be inserted in to the database. The php file is autogenerated from the database. In Button handler i wrote the following code

```
protected function addBtn_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{ 
namBol= new Naming();
namBol.name=nameTxt.text; 
createNamingResult.token = namingService.createNaming(namBol);
}
```

The database has only two feilds, sr_no and name. While running this code, on clicking the addBtn the name does not get inserted into the database. What might be the problem?

Here is the whole code, let me know if I miss something.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
   xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
   xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
   xmlns:valueObjects="valueObjects.*" 
   xmlns:namingservice="services.namingservice.*" 
   minWidth="955" minHeight="600" 
> 
<fx:Declarations> 
<valueObjects:Naming id="namBol"/> 

<s:CallResponder id="createNamingResult"  result="createNamingResult_resultHandler(event)"/> 
<namingservice:NamingService id="namingService" 
       fault="Alert.show(event.fault.faultString + '\n' + event.fault.faultDetail)" 
       showBusyCursor="true"/> 
<!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here --> 
</fx:Declarations> 

<fx:Script> 
<![CDATA[ 
import mx.controls.Alert; 
import mx.events.FlexEvent; 
import mx.rpc.events.ResultEvent; 
protected function addBtn_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void 
{ 
    namBol= new Naming(); 
    namBol.name=nameTxt.text; 
    createNamingResult.token = namingService.createNaming(namBol);   
} 
]]> 
</fx:Script> 
<s:TextInput id="nameTxt" x="216" y="144" /> 
<s:Button id="addBtn" x="217" y="204" label="Button"   click="addBtn_clickHandler(event)"/>  
</s:Application>
```

Answer (score 0):

in your function `addBtn_clickHandler` add :

`namingService.commit();`